# IdentityServer4 Integration Testing with InMemory Stores

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, identityserver4

I'm writing an integration test for my microservices authentication and authorization. I am using IdentityServer4 with in-memory stores and my code looks like this;

EDIT: I have added the SQLite in memory setup that I am using. Not sure if I need that for IS4 InMemory stores.

```
var builder = services
    .AddIdentityServer(options =>
    {
        options.IssuerUri = "https://my.services.is4host";
        options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
        options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
        options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
        options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
    });

var migrationAssembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;  

var inMemorySqlite = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=:memory:");
inMemorySqlite.Open();

services
    .AddDbContext<SecurityDbContext>(
        options => options.UseSqlite(inMemorySqlite,
            sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationAssembly)));

// Migrate the database
var context = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<SecurityDbContext>();
context.Database.Migrate();

builder
    .AddInMemoryClients(IS4Config.GetClients())
    .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(IS4Config.GetIdentityResources())
    .AddInMemoryApiResources(IS4Config.GetAPIResources())
    .AddTestUsers(new List<TestUser>
    {
            new TestUser {
                SubjectId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                Claims = new List<Claim> {
                    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Subject, MyDemoUser.ElevatedUser.UserName),
                    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Email, MyDemoUser.ElevatedUser.Email),
                    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, MyDemoUser.ElevatedUser.Roles[0]),
                    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, MyDemoUser.ElevatedUser.Roles[1])
                },
                IsActive = true,
                Password = MyDemoUser.ElevatedUser.Password,
                Username = MyDemoUser.ElevatedUser.UserName
            },
            new TestUser {
                SubjectId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                Claims = new List<Claim> {
                    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Subject, MyDemoUser.WorkstationUser.UserName),
                    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Email, MyDemoUser.WorkstationUser.Email),
                    new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, MyDemoUser.WorkstationUser.Roles[0])
                },
                IsActive = true,
                Password = MyDemoUser.WorkstationUser.Password,
                Username = MyDemoUser.WorkstationUser.UserName
            }
    });
```

and my test looks like this;

```
var is4Host = new WebApplicationTestFactory<Services.IS4Host.Startup>();
var client = is4Host.CreateClient();

var disco = await client.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync("https://My.services.is4host");
if (disco.IsError)
{
    Console.WriteLine(disco.Error);
    return false;
}

// request token
var tokenResponse = await client.RequestPasswordTokenAsync(new PasswordTokenRequest
{
    Address = disco.TokenEndpoint,
    ClientId = MyClient.ClientId,
    ClientSecret = MyClient.ClientSecret,
    Scope = MyApiResource.Gateway.Name,
    UserName = user.UserName,
    Password = user.Password
});

if (tokenResponse.IsError)
{
    Console.WriteLine(tokenResponse.Error);
    return false;
}

Console.WriteLine(tokenResponse.Json);
Console.WriteLine("\n\n");

return true;
```

I am adding records into the in memory stores but I keep getting the response below from IS4

```
{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "invalid_username_or_password"
}
```

Comment: Try get rid of the `Claims` you add to each user. Other than that, maybe as per error there is issue with username and password.

Comment: No luck. I am wondering how my test (in memory) data is being stored in IS4.

Comment: Well it should only be stored in memory. The only thing that i can see missing from your setup is `builder.AddDeveloperSigningCredential();` compared to the quickstart samples.

Comment: I am using the same static object for my username and password so I really doubt that it is what's causing this

Comment: Due to the lack of visibility into what the username and password are I have to ask whether you double checked whether the correspond to either MyDemoUser.WorkstationUser.UserName and MyDemoUser.WorkstationUser.Password, or  MyDemoUser.ElevatedUser.UserName and  MyDemoUser.ElevatedUser.Password?

Comment: Yes, they are the same. In fact they are coming from the same static "Class Enumarator"